# Check onload to see if element visible, if not show another element

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up some jQuery to check if a hotspot is visible on the screen to determine if a help message displays on screen or not. If the hotspot is visible it should not display the help message at all.

So far I've got some script to turn off the help message if you hover the hotspot after the help message fades in. However, I'm unsure how to check before the help message fades in if the hotspot has been hovered.

The main reason for this functionality is that both messages are in the same place on the page and at the moment it creates a stacking effect.

Please find my script along with an example of the issue so far below.
If you hover over the hotspot and then refresh the window with the cursor still on the hotspot you should see my problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.ws-hotspot').hover(function(){
  
  console.log("appeared");
  $('#ws-hotspot-helper').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).find(".ws-hotspot-view-more").animate({opacity: 0.8, marginLeft: "26px"},200);
 },function(){
  $('#ws-hotspot-helper').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).find(".ws-hotspot-view-more").stop().animate({opacity: 0, marginLeft: "22px"},50);
 });


 
 function hotspotHelper(){
  if(!$('#ws-hotspot-one .ws-hotspot-view-more').css('opacity') == 0.8){
   console.log("appeared");
   $('#ws-hotspot-helper').css('display', 'none');
  }
  else {
   $('#ws-hotspot-helper').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
  };
 
 };

 $(hotspotHelper);
});
```

```css
 .ws-hotspot{
  z-index: 9999;
  position:absolute;
  background:blue;
  width:55px;
  height:55px;
 }
 
  #ws-hotspot-helper{
  background:yellow;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 1px -22px;
  display: none;
  min-width: 130px;
  padding: 0.37rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
     top: calc(16% + 9px);
     left: calc(58% + 27px);
  border-radius: 3px 10px 10px 3px;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  color: #58595b;
 }
 
 #ws-hotspot-helper span#ws-hotspot-helper-arrow{
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-weight:400;
  font-size:1rem;
 }

 .ws-hotspot .ws-hotspot-view-more{
  display: inline-block;
     opacity: 0;
  background:yellow;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px -22px;
     margin-left: 24px;
     margin-top: 9px;
     min-width: 80px;
     padding: 7px;
  padding-left: 25px;
     font-size: 0.87rem;
     border-radius: 3px 10px 10px 3px;
  border:1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-width:1px 1px 1px 0px;
  color:#58595b;
  text-align:center;
 }
 
 .ws-hotspot#ws-hotspot-one{
     top: 16%;
     left: 58%;
 }

 #red-box{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red-box">
 <span id="ws-hotspot-helper"><span id="ws-hotspot-helper-arrow">&#9664;&nbsp;</span>find out more</span>
 <a href="#"><span class="ws-hotspot" id="ws-hotspot-one"><span class="ws-hotspot-view-more">view more</span></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the .fadeIn() would still run on the ws-hotspot-helper element after the .delay() despite the if statement setting it to display none. Therefore I switched out the line:

$('#ws-hotspot-helper').css('display', 'none');

For

$('#ws-hotspot-helper').remove();

This solved the problem instantly as it simply takes it out of the page on hover of the "view more" element.

Hope I helped someone out by replying to this.